# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Vuex/Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

i'm trying to refactor my vuex in nuxt to separate my actions, mutaionss, getters and state into different file, but now i'm getting errors;

store/template/state.js file like so

```
export const state = () => ({
  objective: {
    active: true,
    finished: false,
  },
  credence: {
    active: false,
    finished: false,
  },
  complete: {
    active: false,
    finished: false,
  },
  essentialScore: 50,
  socialScore: 0,
  governmentScore: 0,
  addressScore: 0,
  templateDetails: {
    name: 'love',
    services: [],
    credence: {
      essentials: {
        firstname: 25,
        lastname: 25,
      },
      socials: {},
      governmentId: {},
      address: {},
    },
  },
})
```

and in my component like so

```
 templateName: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.template.templateDetails.name
      },
      set(value) {
        return this.$store.dispatch('template/setTemplateName', value)
      },
      //   },
    },
```

store/template/action.js

```
export default {
  setTemplateName({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('SET_TEMPLATE_NAME', payload)
  },
 
}
```

store/template/mutation.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default {
  SET_TEMPLATE_NAME(state, payload) {
    state.templateDetails.name = payload
  },
}
```

Comment: Please, add your store file. To see how you implement state.js

Comment: @Asimple I separated them into different filles

Comment: I see that you separated them, but how you build your store? Make them together?

Comment: @Asimple okay, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to split your module into different files (for state, mutations, etc.), you should use the default export in each file instead of `export const state`.

```js
export default () => ({
  templateDetails: {
    name: 'love',
    // ...
  }
})
```

The syntax you are using in only good if you have a single file for your store module.

See [documentation here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#modules).